async thread vs std thread
I'm curious about when to use tokio threads versus std threads.
In the past, I always thought async threads were for IO tasks and std threads were for CPU tasks.
However, from this discussion (https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/13uvmr4/using_tokiospawn_vs_stdthreadspawn_for_a_game/), people mention that you can also write CPU tasks in async and await them.
So, I've come to these conclusions, but I'm not sure if they're correct:

If you only have IO tasks, use async threads.
If you only have CPU tasks, use std threads.
If you have mixed tasks, use async threads.


Here's my context: I'm going to spawn 4 services where each service is asynchronous.
Should I use:
for _ in 0..4 {
    std::thread::spawn(tokio::runtime::Runtime::new()?.block_on(..))
}

Or
let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .worker_threads(4)
        .enable_all()
        .build()?;

for _ in 0..4 {
    rt.spawn(..)
}

Initially, I thought 4 std threads with 4 tokio runtimes would be more efficient. Now I'm unsure. Which setup performs better?

You can achieve maximum efficiency only with raw threads and manual control over them. For example Tokio comes with scheduler overhead. Still, whether it matters is a different question, and you would have to measure yourself. It is possible that features implemented by Tokio out of the box will be more important.

Yes, I understand. To benefit from tokio, services need to be asynchronous. I'm asking which option is better for booting them from the main in such mixed mode.

As I said: if you need to squeeze every drop of performance from that orange, then raw threads. Otherwise Tokio almost certainly will be more useful.

I think we need to look at why we use async/await before we can answer this question. Async/await is a technique that allows for better usage of CPU resources on IO-bounded tasks by switching to other pending tasks when attempting to await a value that is not yet ready. On the other hand, what you refer to as std threads are actually OS threads. In that case, the OS manages scheduling and switching between threads during execution.
Importantly, async/await runtimes are written on top of OS threads. OS threads can do everything async/await can do and more. However, they are generally very expensive to use. If I want to start a new OS thread, I need to tell the OS about it and then wait for the system scheduler to actually start it. That new thread also requires allocating system resources (like setting up a new system stack). Plus, every thread of every process on your machine is competing for CPU time, so yielding to the OS scheduler does not guarantee the OS will choose to switch to a thread you are interested in.
As an example, lets say I wanted to write a simple web server. One approach using OS threads would be to create a new thread for every new connection I receive, tell the OS to block on that thread until we have received the full request, then send our response. However, we don't really need a full OS thread for each connection to complete this goal. An async/await program might use a single OS thread and handle the connections and incoming data with non-blocking calls one after another. In this way, we make much better use of the OS resources leading to overall better performance under load.
If we want to, we can do all the same things ourselves using OS-threads (for more info look into epoll), but it is not a very enjoyable process. The real genius of async/await is that it lets us write programs that make use of non-blocking IO in an intuitive linear manor similar to its blocking counterpart. Technically speaking, OS threads will be able to achieve better performance 100% of the time. However, that doesn't really mean much. It is also true that assembly will be able to achieve better performance than <choose any language> 100% of the time.
Rules of Thumb
With that out of the way, there is no one correct answer.

When we refer to "IO-bounded" tasks, we are really only referring to IO involving the network. Even if there are there are some non-blocking ways to read/write to the disk, we are unlikely to see any performance benefits. Operating systems are optimized for blocking IO to the disk and most async/await runtimes (including tokio) use blocking file IO under the hood. In fact, the way tokio implements async/await for files is by creating a new OS thread that runs the blocking IO operation on every call. This is avoids blocking on the main async/await worker threads, but is not exactly ideal either.

Using an async/await runtime is never free. We always pay some performance penalty. However, for use cases like running web servers, we more than make up for that cost in due to the time we save.

Async/await benefits most from situations were we would otherwise need lots of threads with only a little work being needed on any one given thread.

Even if we have a network bounded task, if it would only need at most exactly N threads to complete it (and N is fairly small), then you probably wont benefit from async/await. That being said, if you don't immediately await the result of every async call, an async runtime may be able to multithread some function calls leading to better performance even on CPU-bounded tasks (though this does not really apply to async/await in Rust).

Often you want to either choose one or the other. If you are already using an async runtime, you may as well use it everywhere for consistency. Otherwise, just using OS threads generally makes things simpler.


Conclusions


If you only have IO tasks, use async threads.
If you only have CPU tasks, use std threads.


These first two conclusions generally hold up in most use cases.


If you have mixed tasks, use async threads.


This is highly use-case dependent. Personally, I only use async/await as a last resort due to all of the baggage it brings in and its tendency to infect your codebase (Read What Color is Your Function? for more info). Generally, try to choose an approach when starting a project and stick to that approach everywhere.


So, I've come to these conclusions, but I'm not sure if they're correct:
If you have mixed tasks, use async threads.

That's a dangerous idea, for a simple reason: if you have 4 (or however many worker threads Tokio has) CPU tasks running at the same time all the tokio workers are bound and it's completely unable to do any IO work.
That is why Tokio has spawn_blocking and a second dynamically sized threadpool for blocking tasks.
It is also not an either/or situation, you can use OS threads or rayon and tokio alongside one another, it requires some care at the boundary (e.g. synchronisation / communication primitives), but it's literally what one of tokio's own developers recommends.
Notably spawn_blocking is mostly intended for scheduling blocking IO e.g. filesystem interactions or IO-heavy libraries with a blocking interface e.g. DB library without async support or whatnot, because tokio's "blocking" pool has a pretty high limit by default, so while one or two CPU-heavy tasks would be fine scheduling as many as you can would bring your computer to its knees unless you have a threadripper or two.

Initially, I thought 4 std threads with 4 tokio runtimes would be more efficient.

With the configuration you give it, definitely not:

This results in the multi threaded scheduler, I/O driver, and time driver being initialized.

So you're creating 4 MT runtimes each with as many threads there are cores on your device. They're just going to fight one another for resources.
4 single-threaded runtime would be more efficient because there would be no task migration, however they may be less effective: if one of your services has a lot more work than the rest it's going to be fully loaded while the rest is sleeping.
The multithreaded runtime has a concurrent work-stealing scheduler, so it can move tasks between workers, which is less efficient (it requires synchronisation and may have higher cache thrashing so would likely have a higher CPU usage) but is a more effective use of resources (will likely have lower walltime and latency).
